# Why is my server responding with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) in spring?

Tags: java, jquery

I am passing the (jsp)form details with some other data,to controller (spring).And getting a error in browser console as the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error):

(Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error))

```
var formElement = document.getElementById("formCccAddAccount");
    var formDetails = new FormData(formElement);
    var otherData = $('#formCccAddAccount').serialize();

        formDetails.append('appNumber', appNumber);
        formDetails.append('fileDetails', fileDetails);
        formDetails.append('formNumber', formNumber);
        formDetails.append('clientID', clientID);
        formDetails.append('accountSequenceNumber',accountSequenceNumber);
        formDetails.append('otherData', otherData); 

        if(datavalid==true){
        $.ajax({
            type : 'post',
            url : 'CorporateClientCreation/accountSave.html',
            data : formDetails,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success : function(json) {
                var obj = JSON.parse(json);
                if (obj.substring(0, 1) == "1") {
                    var data = obj.substring(1);
                    $.msgBox({
                        title : "Error Message",
                        type : "error",
                        content : data
                    });
                } else {
                    var account=obj.split("_");
                    var replayMessage='';
                    if(status==0)
                        replayMessage='Saved Sucessfully';

                    $.msgBox({
                        title : "Message",
                        type : "info",
                        content : replayMessage
                    });

                }
            },
            error : function(e) {
                $.msgBox({
                    title : "Error",
                    type : "error",
                    content : "Error Calling Function"
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

and my controller is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/CorporateClientCreation/accountSave", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
String saveAccounts(HttpSession session, 
        @RequestParam(value = "formNumber") int formNumber, 
        @RequestParam(value = "fileDetails") String fileDetails,
        @RequestParam(value = "clientID") String clientID,
        @RequestParam(value = "appNumber") String appNumber,
        @RequestParam(value = "accountSequenceNumber") String accountSequenceNumber,
         CorporateClientCreationValueObject valueObject
        ) {

    //code
```

Comment: Look in the server's logs.  There will probably be error messages / exception stacktraces.

Comment: Thanks, I got the solution .There was a duplicate path in my form(formCccAddAccount) in jsp.